# Suppose $a,b,c \neq 0$. Show that $\det(1+a,1,1),(1,1+b,1),(1,1,1+c) = abc\left(1 + \frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

Suppose $a,b,c \neq 0$ .Show that the \begin{eqnarray*} \det \begin{bmatrix} 1+a  &1 &1 \\1  &1+b & 1  \\ 1 & 1 & 1+c  \end{bmatrix} =  abc \left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \right). \end{eqnarray*}

I've use cofactor expansion and reduced to get the form
$bc + ac + ab + abc = det$. Choosing a variety of number to plug in for $a,b,$ and $c$, I know I'm on the right track. How can I reduce to get to $$bc + ac + ab + abc = abc\left(1 + \frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c\right)$$

Comment: $ab+ac+bc+abc = abc\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$ is trivial, just expand the RHS.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1+a  &1 &1 \\1  &1+b & 1  \\ 1 & 1 & 1+c 
\end{bmatrix} = (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) -(1+a)-(1+b)-(1-c) +2 =\\ abc+ab+bc+ca  = abc \left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Which equality are you struggling with ?

Comment: I know these things are equal. It's more about showing how I can factor abc + ab + bc + ca into abc(1 + 1/a + 1/b + 1/c)

Comment: As Jack says ... expand the bracket to check the last equality is sound..

Answer (score 1):

$$abc(1 + {1\over a} + {1\over b} + {1\over c})= abc \cdot 1 + abc \cdot {1\over a}+ abc \cdot {1\over b}+ abc \cdot {1\over c}= abc + bc + ac + ab$$